# When opacity for a group is reduced the groups behind it is being visible in sketchapp. Is there a way to make it opaque?

Tags: sketch-app

When opacity for a group is reduced the groups behind it is being visible in sketchapp. Is there a way to make reduce the opacity of a foreground layer without making the layers behind it  Inkscape seems to not have this problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand.. you want to lower opacity but keep objects opaque?? That's illogical.

Comment: I suppose you are right. It is the same in Inkscape as well.